# Use of tail() in out-of-sample prediction

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting, tail

Below you see an out of sample rolling window estimation I found here: (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/11/formal-ways-to-compare-forecasting-models-rolling-windows/)

Here is my question: I know the tail() function returns the last n rows of a dataset. But I don't understand its purpose when its used in the random walk in line 13 or when calculating the errors in line 17 and 18. Any help on clarifying this would be much appreciated.

```
# = Number of windows and window size
w_size = 300
n_windows = nrow(X) - 300
# = Rolling Window Loop = #
forecasts = foreach(i=1:n_windows, .combine = rbind) %do%{
  # = Select data for the window (in and out-of-sample) = #
  X_in = X[i:(w_size + i - 1), ] # = change to X[1:(w_size + i - 1), ] forxpanding window
  X_out = X[w_size + i, ]

 # = Regression Model = #
 m1 = lm(infl0 ~ . - prodl0, data = X_in)
 f1 = predict(m1, X_out)

  # = Random Walk = #
  f2 = tail(X_in$infl0, 1)

  return(c(f1, f2))
}

# = Calculate and plot errors = #
e1 = tail(X[ ,"infl0"], nrow(forecasts)) - forecasts[ ,1]
e2 = tail(X[ ,"infl0"], nrow(forecasts)) - forecasts[ ,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the function `tail` is applied to a vector because you select only the `"inf10"` column. In this case tail return the last element of the selected column.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2), B = c(3,4))
df[,"A"] # will return c(1,2)
tail(df[,"A"], 1) # will return 2
tail(df$B, 1) # will return 4
```

Comment: Okay so the random walk will stay constant at the last element of infl0? And in the error the first part “ tail(X[ ,"infl0"], nrow(forecasts))” means that we take all the numbers of rows in the forecast for the infl0 variables ?.. I am using the errors to get RMSE = sqrt(mean(e1^2)) and R^2=1-MSE(regression)/MSE(RW)= 1-mean(e1^2)/mean(e2^2)... But I am not sure my Rolling window forecast is correct because I dont fully understand it. Do you think its correct?

Comment: The last `tail` will get the `n` last rows of `X`, `n` being the number of row of `forecast`. I don't really understand your rolling window, I'll check the link you provided (never used forecast package before)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, since the error should show the difference between the forecasted value and the actual value.. And yes if you Can do that I would be forever grateful

Comment: Did you check it?